# OnResume is firing instead of OnStart and onCreate

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to show toast on every life cycle but upon running the application the OnStart and OnCreate gets skipped and OnResume only runs, same with other life cycle methods. But whenever II remove the OnResume, OnStart is firing but onCreate is not.

EDIT:
this code works, but I run the application on my smartphone which is Xiaomi.
Tried running on emulator and everything works, correct me if I'm wrong

my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//launch
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resume!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


//stopping
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pause!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Destroy!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
}
@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Restart!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: The code seems no problems. Try invalidate cache and restart Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this code works, but I run the application on my smartphone which is Xiaomi. Tried running on emulator and everything works, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You should just close the Question.